# Ruby Function multiple items

Tags: ruby

Adding the correct code to iterate through the items based on arrays

```
Maid.rules do
search = ["Test01","Test02","Test03","Forever.US.","Castle.US."]
replace =["Item-1","Item-2","Item-3","Forever.2014.","Castle.2009."]
def rename_item(path, search, replace)
    Dir[path].each do |show|
        old = show
        new = show.gsub(search, replace)
        puts "Reanaming #{old} to #{new}"
        `mv #{old} #{new}`
    end
end
    rule '[TEST]' do    
       dir(['~/RubyTest/**/*.{txt}']).each do |shows|
           search.each_with_index {|item, idx| rename_item(shows,search[idx], replace[idx]) if shows.include?(item)}
       end
    end
end
```

This seems to work not sure if it is the best way to do this though

Comment: What is `dir(['~/Downloads/TV/**/*.{mp4,mkv,m4v}'])`?

Comment: update original post

Comment: You want to search and update more items in `rename_item`?

Comment: Yes that would be ideal give it a list of items to search along with rename items if it finds any of them then perform the action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an array of search items and replace items.

```
def rename_item(path, search, replace)
    replace = search.zip replace
    Dir[path].each do |show|
        old = show
        replace.each {|item| show.gsub!(item[0], item[1])}
        new = show
        puts "Reanaming #{old} to #{new}"
        `mv #{old} #{new}`
    end
end
```